# ERRO: Operand should countain 1 column(s) - CASE WHEN... THEN

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando rodar este código MySql para realizar uma clusterização de tempo de empresa porém está apresentando o erro 1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s) . Alguém pode me apoiar?

```
SELECT 
*,
(case WHEN (vw_rol.Tempo_empresa <= 0,3) THEN "até 3 meses"
     WHEN (vw_rol.Tempo_empresa > 0,3) and (vw_rol.Tempo_empresa <= 0,5)THEN "de 4 a 5 meses"
     WHEN (vw_rol.Tempo_empresa > 0,5) and (vw_rol.Tempo_empresa <= 0,11)THEN "de 6 a 11 meses"
     WHEN (vw_rol.Tempo_empresa > 0,11) and (vw_rol.Tempo_empresa <= 3)THEN "de 1 a 2 anos"
     WHEN (vw_rol.Tempo_empresa >=3) and (vw_rol.Tempo_empresa < 7)THEN "de 3 a 6 anos"
     WHEN (vw_rol.Tempo_empresa >=7) and (vw_rol.Tempo_empresa < 11)THEN "de 7 a 10 anos"
     WHEN (vw_rol.Tempo_empresa >=11) and (vw_rol.Tempo_empresa < 16)THEN "de 11 a 15 anos"
     WHEN (vw_rol.Tempo_empresa >=16) and (vw_rol.Tempo_empresa < 21)THEN "de 16 a 20 anos"
     WHEN (vw_rol.Tempo_empresa >20) THEN "de 16 a 20 anos"
    else "" 
    end) as CLASSIFICACAO
 
from vw_rol
```

Comment: Erro de sintaxe. Troque a virgula por ponto.

Answer (score 1):

A sintaxe dos decimais é `0.5` e não `0,5`. Troque isso nos filtros da sua query.

Comment: Muito obrigado!